# Why is this odd file extension appearing when I scp a file?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, cp

I'm creating a large number of gifs and copying them to a separate computer with a webserver folder mounted via sshfs.

For some reason the files will randomly copy with `*.gif.001` file extensions. My scripted command is:

```
scp IMG_* USER@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:/home/USER/MOUNTED_FOLDER/
```

Where `IMG_*` is the file pattern (i.e. `IMG_1.gif`, `IMG_2.gif`, etc)

I am generating new images to replace files with the same name in the web folder.

Does anyone know how to stop the `*.001` file extensions from appearing?

Comment: Quite honestly I kind of doubt it's a result of scp work. That would be a bit bizarre, as scp normally overwrites files if they exist. Have you actually checked what's really in your source dir before you started copying files?

Comment: I'm not quite 100% sure but I think this might be a temporary file.


Do you still have those files when the copy process is done?

Comment: Maybe they are supposed to be temporary? The originals definitely don't update when the *.00# files are generated. Here is the web directory where these files are going as an example: http://weather.uncc.edu/data/nexrad/CLT/

Comment: Could it be some sort of automated version control system on the destination computer?

Comment: WxPilot - anyway - if you don't want temporary/backup files copied, you may use rather IMG_*.gif instead, to copy only the files you're interested in. How to prevent creation of temporary files is rather kind of separate subject, I'd say - referring rather to the app you use for processing pictures.

Comment: The application was the issue, as everyone pointed out, cp was doing its job and copying everything. As it turns out, the application generates the images but if it can't do a direct replacement it generates a *.00# file. My fix was to clear the old images from the folder where the images are made before running the program, and do a more specific cp as Jacek suggested.. So should this question be flagged or answered? Considering scp wasn't the issue

Answer (score 1):

The application was the issue since, as everyone suggested, scp functionality means these files would never appear.

As it turns out, the application I use was generating the `*.00#` files if it couldn't do a direct replacement.

My fix was to remove the old images from the folder before running the program, and do a more specific `cp`, as Jacek suggested in the comments (i.e. `scp IMG_*.gif USER@SERVER:XX.XX.XXX.XXX:/home/USER/`)